# Stream video to another computer using OBS

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, video-capture

I'd like to take multiple video streams and display them one at a time, with the ability to swap between them. I was thinking about taking the video output from OBS and stream it to a private server using [RMTP and nginx](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/). Then I'd write some code (C/C++ maybe) to swap which stream is being displayed.

My first question is, would this even work? Would I be able to process the video being streamed to the server using this method, or would I need to send it to the server a different way? (preferably still using OBS)

My second question is, what would be a good place to get started for processing the streams? Are there any tutorials or forms that could be helpful?

I've never done any sort of video processing, so if I'm missing a key component I apologize ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly OBS gives you a couple of options to achieve this. You can create a different scene for each video input, select the scene to display the input of your choice. If you use the studio version it has a built in transition effects. Alternatively you can add all the video sources to one scene then move your desired source to the top. Using this method you can resize the sources and display more than one at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,upstairs is right.or you can use mimoLive.app if you are a macOS user